# A substitute for NSGlyph's -glyphIsEncoded:?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

While porting some ***ancient*** code over, I came across a peculiar class that was mostly deprecated in OS X 10.4 called NSGlyph.  After googling around a while, I came up with [very few hits](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2002/Jan/msg01116.html) as to exactly what it did, and why it was important to the if-else branches in the framework.  In particular, the method `NSFont -glyphIsEncoded:` seems to be a big part of some of the branches, and it would be a shame for me to just gut it and move on in case something were to break.  Does anybody know of a suitable substitute for `NSFont -glyphIsEncoded:`?

```
if (glyph == 0xffff || ![font glyphIsEncoded:glyph]) {
    // Switch to getting it from the system font for "normal" keys
    // get the glyph from the layout manager (this normally will be the ascii value)
    glyph = [layoutManager glyphAtIndex: i];
font = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:[font pointSize]]; // use the system font
        //NSLog(@"Asking layout manager for glyph for %@, got %d", glyphName, glyph);
    }
    if (glyph != 0xffff && [font glyphIsEncoded:glyph]) {
        NSRect bounds = [font boundingRectForGlyph:glyph];
        [path moveToPoint: NSMakePoint(left, 0.0 - [font descender])];
        [path appendBezierPathWithGlyph: glyph inFont: font];
    left += [font advancementForGlyph: glyph].width;
        continue; // rendered a character
    } //etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFont_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000382-glyphIsEncoded_),

```
[font glyphIsEncoded:glyph]
```

can be replaced by

```
glyph < [font numberOfGlyphs]
```

Comment: Ah, thank you.  For some reason, the documentation doesn't appear as a search result for NSGlyph... weird.  Any idea what the class is for?

Comment: @CodaFi: All fonts contains [glyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) which are numbered consecutively. (This is definitely true for TrueType fonts, things are a bit different for PostScript fonts.) `NSGlyph` is just an `unsigned int` to specify a certain glyph in a font. In the TrueType specification this number is called "glyph id". Mostly you don't work with the glyph id, because the font also has a "character mapping" which does the mapping from the character encoding (e.g. Unicode) to the glyph id in the font. You need if you want to specify a glyph by name, see `glyphWithName:`.